# Apple Magic Keyboard/Trackpad 2 will pair with but wont connect to linux device

Tags: bluetooth, linux-device-driver, archlinux, bluez

I have been using Apple's latest version of the Magic Keyboard and Magic Trackpad on my Archlinux machine for a while by establishing a USB connection. This works just fine.
Now, in order to minimize cable clutter on my desk I want to use both of them using a wireless bluetooth connection.

Finding and pairing with either of the two works just fine, but connecting fails every time.
I have tried both `bluetoothctl` and `blueman-manager`.

While `blueman-manager` gives a "Connection Failed: Input/Output error" error message, this is what happens if I try to connect using `bluetoothctl`:

```
➜  ~ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# power on
Changing power on succeeded
[bluetooth]# pairable on
Changing pairable on succeeded
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller 00:19:86:00:0F:AF Discovering: yes
[NEW] Device 50:A0:09:B0:5B:F7 50-A0-09-B0-5B-F7
[NEW] Device 56:43:CD:7D:4B:7C 56-43-CD-7D-4B-7C
[NEW] Device 2C:33:61:E2:30:C0 Magic Keyboard
[bluetooth]# pair 2C:33:61:E2:30:C0 
Attempting to pair with 2C:33:61:E2:30:C0
[CHG] Device 2C:33:61:E2:30:C0 Connected: yes
Request confirmation
[agent] Confirm passkey 194572 (yes/no): yes
[CHG] Device 2C:33:61:E2:30:C0 UUIDs: 00001124-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 2C:33:61:E2:30:C0 UUIDs: 00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device 2C:33:61:E2:30:C0 ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device 2C:33:61:E2:30:C0 Paired: yes
Pairing successful
[CHG] Device 2C:33:61:E2:30:C0 ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device 2C:33:61:E2:30:C0 Connected: no
[bluetooth]# trust 2C:33:61:E2:30:C0 
[CHG] Device 2C:33:61:E2:30:C0 Trusted: yes
Changing 2C:33:61:E2:30:C0 trust succeeded
[CHG] Device 2C:33:61:E2:30:C0 RSSI: -51
[bluetooth]# connect 2C:33:61:E2:30:C0 
Attempting to connect to 2C:33:61:E2:30:C0
[CHG] Device 2C:33:61:E2:30:C0 Connected: yes
Connection successful
[CHG] Device 2C:33:61:E2:30:C0 Connected: no
[CHG] Device 2C:33:61:E2:30:C0 Class: 0x00000540
[CHG] Device 2C:33:61:E2:30:C0 Icon: input-keyboard
[CHG] Device 2C:33:61:E2:30:C0 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 2C:33:61:E2:30:C0 Connected: no
```

Now, whenever I press any key on the keyboard/touch the trackpad these last two lines are repeated:

```
[CHG] Device 2C:33:61:E2:30:C0 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 2C:33:61:E2:30:C0 Connected: no
```

I suspect this is some sort of driver problem, but I'm not sure.